# How to create responsive drop downs using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a personal project and I am having trouble saving and using the values selected from dropdown lists. For example:

```
<select id = "CarType" onchange = "cartype()">
    <option value = "car"> Car </option>
    <option value = "suv"> SUV </option>
</select>
```

So the functionality I am trying to create is that a user will select "SUV" and then due to that selection I would like to populate 2 more drop down lists listing models of SUV, so the user would select SUV A and SUV B, the output will be "SUV B will be faster!" and the same functionality if user picks car. The 2 resulting dropdowns will be comparison.

Side note: if anyone has any advice relating to where to save this type of comparison data for the function to call upon please let me know.

Comment: Do you need some further explanations?

Comment: @Axel I commented below your solution, if you can advise me on that situation that would be great!

Comment: I'd like to help you but I don't get what you mean. The best would be to make a [pen](https://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/OjoWWo) or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your current mockup (html, css, js)... I need some clarification about your issue(s).

Comment: @Axel I figured it out :) , I was making a syntax mistake

Comment: so everything fine now? :)

Comment: @Axel stuck now :(, I added 2 more lists but for some reason the code for .sub doesn't seem to be implementing. Is it possible to direct message you? The two lists i added are same values and same names, I wanted it so that if a user selects SUV, 2 suv drop downs appear in which they can select whatever model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#CarType').on('change', function() {
  // hide all .sub in advance and filter the one to show by changed value
  $('.sub').hide().filter('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```css
.sub { /* hide all .sub in advance */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="CarType">
    <option value="car"> Car </option>
    <option value="suv"> SUV </option>
</select>

<!-- add .sub select boxes -->
<select id="car" class="sub">
    <option value="car1"> car1 </option>
    <option value="car2"> car2 </option>
</select>

<select id="suv" class="sub">
    <option value="suv1"> suv1 </option>
    <option value="suv2"> suv2 </option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Helped me with my application of the same concept. However I am having issues creating two dropdowns side to side, such as after selecting suv, I would like the user to see 2 side to side drop downs that both contain suv 1 and suv 2. Obviously, it's the same concept but for some reason I am having trouble. I tried div style and align, not getting the expected results. Recommendations?